# Order excel-styled row/column strings

Tags: c#, sorting

I've got a set of strings that represent columns and rows in Excel.

i.e. `"A1, A2, A6, B1, B5"` etc. I'd like to be able to order them from left to right A->Z column styled i.e. `A1,A2,A3,B1,B2,B3,C1,C2,C3`.

Problem is, the strings I have are sometimes going to be like "A1, A6, A2, B4, A3, B7"... is there a way to order the strings in such a way that has a convention of going from left to right sequentially through rows?

i.e. `{"A1", "B5", "A2", "Z4", "Z5, AA12", "B2"}` should be `{"A1", "A2","B2", "B5", "Z4", "Z5, AA12"}`

Comment: Could you, please, provide example(s) of `string`s and the desired outcome(s)? E.g. what is the order for, say, `{"A1", "B5, A1", "A2", "B5", "A1, A2, Z4", "Z4, A1"}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
var list = new List<string>() { "A12", "A1", "B12", "A2", "B1" };
list = list.OrderBy(i => i.Substring(0, 1)).ThenBy(i => int.Parse(i.Substring(1))).ToList();
```

Note that you have to make sure that you have only one letter indicating column.

Comment: Hi Michal, thanks for the response. There is a situation where it is Excel-styled so A will turn to AA past Z. Is there a way to compensate for this?

Comment: follow this as an example and then use a regex to remove the letters and get just the int value